# How to diagnose nuget package dependency issues

Tags: nuget

I have been dealing with a lot of problems around nuget recently where we just get a cryptic message like:

Error       Unable to resolve dependencies. 'XXX 21.0.23-Main' is not compatible with 'YYY 21.0.13-Main constraint: XXX (>= 21.0.23)'.

There are no useful messages beyond this and the package XXX is version 21.0.23 and is accessible. Can anyone suggest any tools or approaches to help me solve these sorts of problems? I have spent days on this, searching for answers, with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like you have specified a release version dependency whilst the NuGet packages are pre-releases.

For a pre-release NuGet package version 21.0.23-Main is a lower version than 21.0.23, which is a release build. So what the error message is telling you is correct.

So you will either need to change the dependency version to 21.0.22 or specify a pre-release version as the dependency. Similar to:

```
XXX (>= 21.0.23-alpha1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is this documented somewhere and I just missed it?

Comment: A quick look at the NuGet docs there is paragraph on the versioning page about how the pre-release versions compare with release versions - https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning - that is about all I can find.

Comment: I see it, the critical bit of information just sitting there with no fanfare :(  "When you’re ready to release, just remove the dash and the string and that version is considered “higher” than all the prerelease versions. For example, the stable version 1.0.1 is larger than 1.0.1-rc"